# Слетел перевод во "входящих"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> all items

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сам себе вопросы задаёшь?))

Comment: dashboard переведи заодно, которая ссылка на аднинку.

Comment: @Qwertiy это не вопрос, это баг репорт. Воспринимайте его как памятку.

Comment: @Qwertiy "dashboard"? Чего не вижу - того нет.

Comment: Так я ж прошу не увидеть, а перевести: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnkFZ.png

Comment: @Qwertiy какой перевод желаете?

Comment: Страница называется "Инструменты модератора", вкладка - "история". Как перевести можно подумать, я бы предложил просто "адмика", тем более, она ведёт на https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/admin.

Comment: @Qwertiy перевёл как «панель модератора» для согласования с имеющимися переводами. Надеюсь в строку поместится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил упрощенный перевод:

> все

На сайте появится не раньше понедельника.